# how to select a particular data from array response data and pass it as input to next thred in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

1.first request given me an array of values as response for a query parameter search API in Jmeter.
Reg ex : `"data”:\[(“.+?”)\]`

[image]
2.now i want to select one/first value among the response data.
3. pass the selected value as input for the next thread.
 I am looking for solution without using shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into your regular expression it seems you're trying to extract something from JSON response, I believe the easiest option would be switching to [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and use the following JSONPath query:

```
$..data[0]
```

If it doesn't return what you're looking for please update your question with full response and what do you want to get from there so we could come up with the most elegant and performing solution.

In the mean time check out the following material:

- [JSON - Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)
- [JSONPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

Regular Expression Configuration:

```
Reference Name: anything
Regular Expression: (.+)
Template: $1$
Match No.(O for Random): 1
```

The `Reference Name` should be passed as the variable `${ReferenceNameUsedInReGex}` in the next HTTP request URL path/body

[image: 1.][image]

[image][image]

Comment: Reg ex: "data":[(".+?")] sample data : {"success":true,"message":"success","data":["0dd43050-f8f3-1‌​1e6-97e3-6fa8c293a87‌​1","1829f6f0-ece8-11‌​e6-b2db-11bf5339cef5‌​","1a40f920-f585-11e‌​6-a9fe-d52437143bbe"‌​]}  here I want to select "0dd43050-f8f3-11e6-97e3-6fa8c293a871" / Random value from array response data. so that the selected value will be passed as input to next thread in request. – kiran 14 mins ago

Comment: This is JSON Response. So Use [JSON path extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=JSONPathExtractor) instead if Regular Expression Extractor.

Comment: Use JSon path as `$..data[0]` so , it will extract the value "0dd43050-f8f3-11e6-97e3-6fa8c293a871" from the response.